# Insert distinct records from duplicate valued records in DATASTAGE

Tags: sql, oracle, datastage

Hi I am using DATASTAGE to import hive data into Oracle, I don't have any primary key constraints in hive but on Oracle I am having a combination primary key.
For example I have a data which doesn't have duplicates on basis of whole record but the pk constraints has duplicate
Table has columns
Table name: item_details ;--(hive)
no primary key constraints

> Id mfg_date   item  exp_date
>
> ---
>
> 1  12-01-2018 abc   31-03-2018
>
> 2  12-01-2018 cde   28-02-2018
>
> 3  15-01-2018 efg   10-04-2018
>
> 4  12-01-2018 abc   10-04-2018

Where the mfg_date and item together are primary key for the target table(Oracle) which is same structure.

And I need to push the data into target table.

But it says a primary key violation  and gets aborted.

Can anybody give me a solution.

**Ps. We cannot change the schema for the tables**

Comment: Remove the duplicates to avoid that error

Comment: That is not possible, IAM not the owner of the source data

Comment: Well there is a remove duplicate stage in DataStage - so it is possible

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use `[[twt]]` for.  it's faster than doing Lookup and join stages.

start by changing the output sql from `Insert` to `Custom SQL`.

then you can create a custom SQL Statement like the one below:

```
insert into <<target table>>
select Id, mfg_date, item, exp_date from [[twt]]
where not exist (select 1 from <<target table>> where <<target table>>.id = [[twt]].id)
```

it'll fire off records that don't exist.
because `custom sql` allows for multiple statements, you can do your whole update this way.

By using `[[twt]]`, you can change this to an ELT form of loading, and control the inserts.

thanks.